# How to send authenticated requests to Google Reader?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20, google-reader, google-authentication

It seems that Google has disabled the old way of sending cookie SID to their Google Data Services, specifically Google Reader.

[This way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471898/google-app-engine-with-clientlogin-interface-for-objective-c) does not work at least for me:

```
//create request
NSString* content = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"accountType=HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE&Email=%@&Passwd=%@&service=ah&source=myapp", [loginView username].text, [loginView password].text];
NSURL* authUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin"];
NSMutableURLRequest* authRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:authUrl];
[authRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[authRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
[authRequest setHTTPBody:[content dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

NSHTTPURLResponse* authResponse;
NSError* authError;
NSData * authData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:authRequest returningResponse:&authResponse error:&authError];      

NSString *authResponseBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:authData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

//loop through response body which is key=value pairs, seperated by \n. The code below is not optimal and certainly error prone. 
NSArray *lines = [authResponseBody componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
NSMutableDictionary* token = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (NSString* s in lines) {
        NSArray* kvpair = [s componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
        if ([kvpair count]>1)
                [token setObject:[kvpair objectAtIndex:1] forKey:[kvpair objectAtIndex:0]];
}

//if google returned an error in the body [google returns Error=Bad Authentication in the body. which is weird, not sure if they use status codes]
if ([token objectForKey:@"Error"]) {
        //handle error
};
```

And the request:

```
TTURLRequest *request = [TTURLRequest requestWithURL:url delegate:self];
request.cachePolicy = cachePolicy;
request.cacheExpirationAge = TT_CACHE_EXPIRATION_AGE_NEVER;

NSString *cookieHeader = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name=SID;SID=%@;Domain=.google.com;Path=/;Expires=160000000000", sid];
[request setValue:cookieHeader forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];

[request setHttpMethod:@"GET"];
[request setValue:@"myapp" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-agent"];
```

Changing to use the GoogleLogin auth=xxx gives me a NSURLErrorDomain 401

```
TTURLRequest *request = [TTURLRequest requestWithURL:url delegate:self];
request.cachePolicy = cachePolicy;
request.cacheExpirationAge = TT_CACHE_EXPIRATION_AGE_NEVER;

NSString *authorizationHeader = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"GoogleLogin auth=%@", auth];
[request setValue:authorizationHeader forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

[request setHttpMethod:@"GET"];
[request setValue:@"myapp" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-agent"];
```

The result is always the 401 error code. Could someone show me how to fix in this specific case? Thank you in advance.

```
    Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=401 "Operation could not be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error 401.)" 
    Error description: Operation could not be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error 401.)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the body of the POST solves the 401 error. Differences are in the `service`, `source` & `continue`.

```
    NSString* content = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Email=%@&Passwd=%@&service=reader&source=yourapp&continue=http://www.google.com", username, password];
```