# google reader authentication

Tags: iphone, authentication, google-reader

I had developed iphone application which synchronize google reader on iphone. when i login with my google id the status code 200 & after that when token for accessing google reader status code is 403 & token value gives 403 error url for token used "https://www.google.com/reader/api/0/token" i am searching it almost a week please help me out but can't get anything i can send you the code thanx in advance

Comment: my clientlogin Url request is accomplished but when i requested the token from the url "https://www.google.com/reader/api/0/token" it gets no value & posses 403 error. I give you the code if you required

Answer (score 0):

See [Google Reader Authentication problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100078/google-reader-authentication-problem).

Comment: my clientlogin Url request is accomplished but when i requested the token from the url "https://www.google.com/reader/api/0/token" it gets no value & posses 403 error. I give you the code if you required

Comment: Please refer to the above mentioned link, can you successfully get the Auth string from ClientLogin?

Comment: i had replace the https://www.google.com/accounts/clientLogin with https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLoginAuth url but again the same error exhibits 403. Please help me out i am really thankful to you

Comment: First, did you get the Auth from clientLogin?

Comment: Then include the Auth string in HTTP Header when you request the token.

Answer (score 0):

See my example in C#. The requests will be the same, but if you are using Obj-C you will just need to modify the syntax.

[Google Reader API - Getting Feeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400893/google-reader-api-getting-feeds/5599303#5599303)