# Authentication to Google Reader using OAUth

Tags: google-reader

I want to post a URL from my android application to Google Reader. I have authenticated to google Reader using `ClientLogin` (Accessed to unofficial google API).I have received response code 200, but I was not able to post this url to Google Reader. I have used JSOUP-1.5.2.jar.

I have seen other procedures to access Official Google Reader using OAuth. Which procedure is better for me to follow so that I can post a message from my android application to Google Reader?

Answer (score 0):

See my example in C# (very similar to Java).

[Google Reader API - Getting Feeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400893/google-reader-api-getting-feeds/5599303#5599303)